# figures in IEEE access articles

Tags: floats, ieeeaccess

I would like to know please, what command to use to insert figures in IEEE access template. Is there a specification about the whereabouts of the figure or can I insert them wherever I want in my document?

This is my first time trying a template so ...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `\Figure[t!](topskip=0pt, botskip=0pt, midskip=0pt){fig1.png}
{Magnetization as a function of applied field.
It is good practice to explain the significance of the figure in the caption.\label{fig1}}`. This command can be found in template file.

Comment: Should it be used for all the figures?

Comment: Sure, the command `\Figure` uses LaTeX `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: You can use standalone.cls to turn tikzfigures into images (faster that way too).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I am not using tikz figures at all. I was asking about where to insert the figure because the command '\begin{figure}[H]' that forces the figure to be in a certain place in the document is not recognized and I was thinking maybe \begin{figure}\centering \includegraphicx{}.... is enough? I mean does the IEEEaccess template handle the position of the figure or is it me that should place wherever I see suitable?

Comment: Yes, IEEE is very particular about figures and captions.  Besides, friends don't let friends use [H].

Comment: So let me rephrase, I should just use command \begin{figure}\centering\includegrapicx{}\label\caption\end{figure} ad the template handles the figure by placing it where it is supposed to, right?  Thank you by the way ;)